# Show that $||\hat{f}||_{\infty}=||f||_1$

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

> For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we define $\hat{f}$ for $\alpha\in
>  \mathbb{R}^n $ as $$\hat{f}(\alpha)=\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}
>  f(x)e^{-i\langle x,\alpha\rangle}\,dx$$ Clearly
>   $||\hat{f}||_{\infty}\le ||f||_1$.  I want to know when does equality
>   hold. Clearly if $f$ is non negative $\hat{f}(\textbf{0})=||f||_1$. So the equality holds.
>   Do there exist a $f$ for which $\hat{f}(\textbf{0})\neq ||f||_1$ but
>   still equality holds in above inequality?

I don't know if such a function really exists. Any hint/Suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f(x) = e^{-x^2} e^{ix}$$

$$\hat f(0) = \int_\mathbb R  e^{-x^2} e^{ix} dx = \frac {\sqrt \pi }{\sqrt[4]e}$$

$$||f||_1 = \int_\mathbb R e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt \pi$$

so $\hat f(0) \neq ||f||_1$

But since $\hat f(\alpha) = \int_\mathbb R e^{-x^2}e^{ix - i\alpha x}dx$, setting $\alpha = 1$ we get

$$\hat f(1) = \int_\mathbb R e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt \pi$$

and from this we deduce $$||\hat f||_\infty = ||f||_1$$

Comment: So, more generally you are saying we can modulate any (nontrivial) nonnegative function, Since this yields a translation of the Fourier transform.

Comment: @PhoemueX very eloquently put! :-)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to get such an $f$ which is negative on a set of measure greater than zero?

Comment: @Sayan uhm.. i don't know actually!

Comment: @Sayan: Take $- e^{-x^2}$ :) But you probably want to have $f(x) < 0$ on a set of positive measure and also $f(x) > 0$ on a set of positive measure, right? I will think about it.